# Losing display after boot up

Tags: display, default, reset

Newbie trying to use Ubuntu on Dell Computer with VGA display and TV as second monitor.

In GUI I set an option that turned off both my screens. Now, when the system boots, the screens go blank. I can boot by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and get the system prompt.

- How can I reset to get the default setting/display back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy,

You can **use shortcut key `Start+P` OR `Command+P`** Key To Toggle Multi-Screen Modes Like Windows.

OR

Log into any tty and run `sudo startx`

Comment: **Start/Command is Start/Command Button of Windows TO launch Start/Command menu in Windows/Mac/Linux.**

Comment: I rebooted, and hit Winows key + P, nothing happened

Comment: I can get to prompt with Ctrl+Alt+F1 but no Gui display works on monitors

Comment: @JTonenet YOu have to enter your passsword pres enter it will log in and then Start+P

Comment: Keep Pressing Start+P [do not hold] till it is not looks like fixed.

Comment: >> After booting enter you password and enter[even if screen is blank] then press start+P. If it does not Works then Log in to tty[ctrl+alt+F1] and run `sudo startx`